# Slow Execution of MySQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, performance, pdo

I have the following query…

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
vPAS_Posts_Users 
WHERE (post_user_id =:id AND post_type != 4) 
AND post_updated >:updated 
GROUP BY post_post_id 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT vPAS_Posts_Users.* FROM PAS_Follow 
JOIN vPAS_Posts_Users ON 
( PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id = vPAS_Posts_Users.post_user_id ) 
WHERE (( PAS_Follow.folw_follower_user_id =:id AND PAS_Follow.folw_deleted = 0 ) 
OR ( post_type = 4 AND post_passed_on_by = PAS_Follow.folw_follower_user_id 
AND post_user_id !=:id )) 
AND post_updated >:updated 
GROUP BY post_post_id ORDER BY post_posted_date DESC LIMIT :limit
```

Where `:id = 7`, `:updated = 0.0` and `:limit=40` for example

My issue is that the query is taking about a minute to return results. Is there anything in this query that I can do to speed up the result?

I am using RDS

********EDIT*********

I was asked to run the query with an EXPLAIN the result is below

[image: EXPLAIN Result from Query]

********EDIT**********
View Definitition

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`MySQLUSer`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vPAS_Posts_Users`
AS SELECT
   `PAS_User`.`user_user_id` AS `user_user_id`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_country` AS `user_country`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_city` AS `user_city`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_company` AS `user_company`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_account_type` AS `user_account_type`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_account_premium` AS `user_account_premium`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_sign_up_date` AS `user_sign_up_date`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_first_name` AS `user_first_name`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_last_name` AS `user_last_name`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_avatar_url` AS `user_avatar_url`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_cover_image_url` AS `user_cover_image_url`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_bio` AS `user_bio`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_telephone` AS `user_telephone`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_dob` AS `user_dob`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_sector` AS `user_sector`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_job_type` AS `user_job_type`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_unique` AS `user_unique`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_deleted` AS `user_deleted`,
   `PAS_User`.`user_updated` AS `user_updated`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_post_id` AS `post_post_id`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_language_id` AS `post_language_id`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_type` AS `post_type`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_promoted` AS `post_promoted`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_user_id` AS `post_user_id`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_posted_date` AS `post_posted_date`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_latitude` AS `post_latitude`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_longitude` AS `post_longitude`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_location_name` AS `post_location_name`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_text` AS `post_text`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_media_url` AS `post_media_url`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_image_height` AS `post_image_height`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_link` AS `post_link`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_link_title` AS `post_link_title`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_unique` AS `post_unique`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_deleted` AS `post_deleted`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_updated` AS `post_updated`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_original_post_id` AS `post_original_post_id`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_original_type` AS `post_original_type`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_passed_on_by` AS `post_passed_on_by`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_passed_on_caption` AS `post_passed_on_caption`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_passed_on_fullname` AS `post_passed_on_fullname`,
   `PAS_Post`.`post_passed_on_avatar_url` AS `post_passed_on_avatar_url`
FROM (`PAS_User` join `PAS_Post` on((`PAS_User`.`user_user_id` = `PAS_Post`.`post_user_id`)));
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you need distinct *, how many fields exist in this table, I would say restrict it to the fields you want and that can improve the query a bit.  Moreover why do you need a group by and a distinct, is there a specific purpose for doing this?

Comment: In a word no I built the query so many times to get the result I wanted that I have not really focused on that, would this be causing an issue?

Comment: Lots of trouble here that may doom your query to poor performance. First, don't use `SELECT *`. CERTAINLY don't use `SELECT DISTINCT *`. Name your columns.  Second, what is the purpose of your `GROUP BY` clauses? Where are your aggregative expressions?  Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html Then, avoid the nonstandard extensions. Third, `OR` clauses can hammer performance. Fourth, please explain what you're trying to do and disclose your table layouts.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for your reply, the purpose of the group by is to ensure only unique results as the view produces multiple duplicate rows for each post.

Comment: Please could you post the VIEW definitions - do you have rights to change the results these return (e.g. to remove duplicates)?

Comment: We once had a problem of a query slowing down to 1 minute or longer. By simply changing `from a join b on` to `from b join a` the performance improved to 100 ms. It might be worth a try.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have posted the view definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    vPAS_Posts_Users 
WHERE 
    post_user_id =:id 
AND post_type != 4 
AND post_updated > :updated 
UNION 
SELECT u.* 
FROM vPAS_Posts_Users u
        JOIN PAS_Follow f ON f.folw_followed_user_id = u.post_user_id
WHERE 
    u.post_updated > :updated
AND (   (f.folw_follower_user_id = :id AND f.folw_deleted = 0) 
    OR  (u.post_type = 4 AND u.post_passed_on_by = f.folw_follower_user_id AND u.post_user_id != :id)
) 
ORDER BY u.post_posted_date DESC;
LIMIT :limit
```

---

### Other improvements

**Indices:**
Be sure you have indices on the following columns:

- PAS_User.user_user_id
- PAS_Post.post_user_id
- PAS_Post.post_type
- PAS_Post.post_updated
- PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id
- PAS_Follow.folw_deleted
- PAS_Post.post_passed_on_by

After that is done, please 1- check the performance again (SQL_NO_CACHE) and 2- extract another explain plan so we can adjust the query.

---

EXPLAIN Results

[image: EXPLAIN Results]

Comment: this is good it has cut down my query time to 10 seconds, is there any further optimisation I could do here to speed up even more?

Comment: @JustinErswell add the limit clause, then try again and tell me the result please

Comment: same time result of 10 seconds

Comment: Thats is epic we are now running this query in 465ms thanks so much you have really helped here!

Comment: We may even be able to go beyond. I suspect there's a conflict between the order by and the limit clause. Could you extract the new explain plan please?

Comment: I have uploaded the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: It looks fine I guess

Answer (score 1):

Here are the some suggestions for the query and view first of all using the `UNION` for the two result sets which might makes your query to work slow instead you can use the `UNION ALL`

### Why i am referring you to use UNION ALL

Reason is both `UNION ALL` and `UNION`  use temporary table for result generation.The difference in execution speed comes from the fact `UNION` requires internal temporary table with index (to skip duplicate rows) while `UNION ALL` will create table without such index.This explains the slight performance improvement when using `UNION ALL`.
`UNION` on its own will remove any duplicate records so no need to use the `DISTINCT` clause, try to only one GROUP BY of the whole result set by subqueries this will also minimize the execution time rather then grouping results in each subquery.

Make sure you have added the right indexes on the columns especially the columns used in the `WHERE,ORDER BY, GROUP BY`, the data types should be appropriate for each column with respect to the nature of data in it like `post_posted_date` should be datetime,date with an index also.

Here is the rough idea for the query

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT * FROM 
vPAS_Posts_Users 
WHERE (post_user_id =:id AND post_type != 4) 
AND post_updated >:updated 

UNION ALL


SELECT vPAS_Posts_Users.* FROM PAS_Follow 
JOIN vPAS_Posts_Users ON 
( PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id = vPAS_Posts_Users.post_user_id 
AND vPAS_Posts_Users.post_updated >:updated) 
WHERE (( PAS_Follow.folw_follower_user_id =:id AND PAS_Follow.folw_deleted = 0 ) 
OR ( post_type = 4 AND post_passed_on_by = PAS_Follow.folw_follower_user_id 
AND post_user_id !=:id )) 

) q
GROUP BY q.post_post_id ORDER BY q.post_posted_date DESC LIMIT :limit
```

**References**

[**Difference Between Union vs. Union All – Optimal Performance Comparison**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

[**Optimize Mysql Union**](http://sql.dzone.com/articles/how-optimize-mysql-union-high)

[**MySQL Performance Blog**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/)

Comment: Thanks for this can you iterate further on the query to produce a working version as this seems to have an issue with the group by

Answer (score 0):

From your explain I can see that most of your table don't have any key except for the primary one, I would suggest you to add some extra key on the columns you're going to join, for example on: PAS_Follow.folw_followed_user_id and vPAS_Posts_Users.post_user_id, just this will result in a big performance boost.

Bye,
Gnagno